# matching dictionary values with values in a list within a dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe with columns, the pertinent ones are ID and name.  I also have a dictionary that pairs ID:name.  I need to match the ID and output the name to the df['name'] column.  The issue that I'm having is that in the dataframe, some IDs have more than one ID each row.  How do I iterate through each ID separately.

the code I have is below.  It works if there is only one ID.  I cannot figure out how to get it to work if there are multiple ids.  I guess it would be considered a sublist?

```
for id_col, name_col in dic1.iteritems():
    df.loc[(df['ID Value'] == id_col), 'name'] = name_col
```

sample dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame( {'ID Value' : [130, (12,45,100), 208], 'name' : ['','','']})
```

df_test >>

```
   ID Value           name
0  130
1  (12, 45, 100)
2  208
```

dic1:

```
 45 Joe 
130 Andy
208 Mary
```

the results I want are:

```
    ID Value       name
 0  130            Andy
 1  (12, 45, 100)  Joe
 2  208            Mary
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how useful it is to mix tuples and numbers as IDs (perhaps converting them all to tuples is the correct solution?).
Anyway, you can do this using apply:

```
In [11]: d = {45: "Joe", 130: "Andy", 208: "Mary"}

In [12]: f_test['ID Value'].apply(lambda x: d.get(x) or next(d.get(y) for y in x if d.get(y)))
Out[12]:
0    Andy
1     Joe
2    Mary
Name: ID Value, dtype: object
```

The function in the apply works by first seeing if the ID is in the dictionary (and tuples won't be) and if it is, go for that, and if it isn't find the first one that is...

---

This is probably worthy of being a proper function:

```
def get_int_or_tuple(x, d=d):
    try:
        return d[x]
    except KeyError:  # hopefully that means it's iterable!
        for y in x:
            if y in d:
                return d[y]

In [21]: f_test['ID Value'].apply(get_int_or_tuple)
Out[21]:
0    Andy
1     Joe
2    Mary
Name: ID Value, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

This will output results as intended, but keep in mind that to the case with multiple ids in the tuple you're only assigning one name.

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {"Joe" : 45, "Andy" : 130, "Mary" : 208}

df = pd.DataFrame( {'ID Value' : [130, (12,45,100), 208], 'name' : ['','','']})

def getKey(match, dict):
    for key, value in dict.iteritems():
        if value == match:
            return key

for row in range(0, len(df)):
    ids = df['ID Value'][row]

    if isinstance(ids, int):
        name = getKey(ids, dic)
        if name != None:
            df['name'][row] = name
    elif isinstance(ids, tuple):
        for id in ids:
            name = getKey(id, dic)
            if name != None:
                df['name'][row] = name

print(df)
        ID Value  name
0            130  Andy
1  (12, 45, 100)   Joe
2            208  Mary

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```